# Finding a confidence interval

Tags: statistics

Given Distribution:

$f(R) =\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\theta^2}(\theta-R),  & \text{for } 0 <R<\theta \\[2ex]
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$

Question:

Find $c$ so that $R<\theta<cR$ is a $(1- \alpha)100$% confidence interval for $\theta$.

The answer to this is $c = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{1- \alpha}}{\alpha}$ but I am unsure as to how to acquire this result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I apologize I was.

Comment: In fact the answer is either $c = \frac{1+ \sqrt{1- \alpha}}{\alpha}$ or $c = \frac{1- \sqrt{1- \alpha}}{\alpha}$, but not both.  You want the solution between $0$ and $1$ when $\alpha$ is between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$R\lt \theta \lt cR$ is equivalent to $ \theta /c \lt R \lt \theta$

So you want to solve  $\Pr(\theta /c \lt R \lt \theta \mid \theta) = 1-\alpha$, i.e. $\displaystyle \int_{\theta /c}^\theta f(R) \, dR = 1- \alpha$.